Is it possible to host an sFTP server in React Native (iOS)?
Trying to receive some files via sFTP and was wondering whether it's possible to create a server on react native (or expo) that listens for incoming data?
I found some solutions for node.js, but so far no luck regarding native options
Tried hosting a sFTP server on react native / expo
